# Bash script to monitor new created directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync, nagios

Anyone to give pointers or ideas.

I have a server, that is running rsync and backs up other servers to itself  on different folders creating new folders by date everyday e.g(2017-03-20).
i want to create a bash script that will check if these backups have run, by checking the created folders and then if all backups were successfully the script will confirm by writing a text file in another folder /Z, the text file with format 20-17-03-20. If any of the backups fail the script should just exit and not create the file.

The whole point is, i will then do a nagios plugin script to be checking this text file daily and sending results to Nagios daily.

Any ideas will be most welcome.

Comment: You can monitor a master folder for modifications like creating new subfolders using inotify tools - google it (inotify monitor folder)

Answer (score 2):

First add the epel repo -

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Then install the inotify-tools -

```
sudo yum install inotify-tools
```

Write a script running and indefinite loop monitoring the specific directory (where you expect the backup script to generate directory).

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do 

inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete /<directory> && /bin/sh <script_confirming _backup>

done
```

The `-e` flag check for mentioned events. You can add up events as per your monitoring requirement.
The `-r` flag will look for all the directories and sub-directories under the mentioned directory recursively.

Comment: Thank you for the info, if i have multiple folders e.g  /d, /e, /w, will i be able to get inotify monitor to check all 3 folders and only write the confirmation file if there have been changes on all 3 folders. In a situation where there are changes on 1 or 2 folders, the script must not write to file.

Comment: In that case, you need to ensure it through script that changes occur in all three folders (using && condition operator) then only run the backup script that you have kept. Try it yourself once. If you are unable to figure out, comment here.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've been told to use php instead of bash and not use inotify monitor.So i'm starting afresh with php.

Comment: A request to up vote if you found it helpful in any case :)